# While loop boolean condition in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, while-loop, boolean

I'm trying to create a while loop where its condition block will result to true or false based on if an exact string match is found in another array. If an exact match is found, it should iterate to the next item in the array until the condition is false.

```
$Name = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
$row = "j"
$i = 0

While($row | Where-Object {$_ -match $Name[$i]}){$i++}
```

The desired output would be $i = 9, because it had to iterate through all of the strings in the $Name array to the 9th string.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[Array]::IndexOf()` instead of a loop:

```
$Name = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
$row = "j"
$i = [Array]::IndexOf($Name, $row)  # -> $i equals 9
```

`$i` will contain `-1`, if no match is found.

---

As for what you tried:

- For exact string-matching, use `-ceq` (the case-sensitive form of the `-eq` operator), not `-match`, because `-match` is for *regex*-based matching (and without anchors finds *substring* matches).
- The logic of your conditional is reversed: you want to keep looping for as long as the string does *not* match.
- Your loop is inefficient, because it uses a pipeline in each iteration; for in-memory data, using mere expressions will be faster.

If you do want to solve this with a PowerShell loop, I suggest a simple `for` loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $Name.Count; ++$i) { if ($row -ceq $Name[$i]) { break } }
```

In this case, `$i` will contain the value of `$Name.Count` if no match is found.